# Older Iron Man where he is remote controlling an Iron Man suit and it shoots up from the basement through a chute

Tags: marvel, episode-identification, iron-man

I think I remember an image of Iron Man/Tony Stark remote controlling an Iron Man suit from a basement. He's sitting in a spherical control chair, and I think that the Iron Man shoots up from a basement through a chute.

I just re-watched all the MCU since 2008, I think it's from earlier than that.

Comment: The suit shoots through a chute? You sure the chute doesn't suit a shoot?

Comment: Was this from a cartoon, or from a comic book?

Comment: Definitely not MCU.... a cartoon is possibility.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw it on TV. I don't remember if it was a cartoon or live action. Definitely not a comic book - I don't read those. I feel it was live-action, but I might be misremembering.       Maybe a movie, maybe a tv series.

Comment: After some googling - it might be in Iron Man: Armored Adventures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be remembering *Rhodes* sending the Iron Man armor to Tony's rescue in *Iron Man: Armored Adventures* S01E03, "Secrets and Lies". Check out the clip below, especially the following timestamps:

- 0'33: suit goes up the chute
- 0'56: shot of the ["spherical control chair"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urcpO.png)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I think this was what I was thinking of. I figured out that it was Iron Man: Armored Adventures, but many thanks for the clip!

Comment: @yulerule you're welcome, enjoy the re-watch! :)